# How to get the value of 2nd td in html table on click of first td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirment where i need to get the value of 2nd td in html table on click of first column in html table. I am using jquery to achieve this.

```
$('.tbody').on('click','tr td:nth-child(1)', function () {
    var id = $(this).closest("td").find('td:eq(1)').text();
    alert(id)
});
```

I am using onclick function to get the value of second td as shown in the above code.But i am getting an empty alert. I dont know where i have gone wrong please help.
As per my understanding **$(this).closest("td").find('td:eq(1)').text()** should search for next td and .text() method should display the value within td isn'tit?

Below snippet will reflect the issue mentioned above

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(function () {
    $('.tbody').on('click','tr td:nth-child(1)', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("td").find('td:eq(1)').text();
        alert(id)
    });
});
```

```css
#items {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#items th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: white;
    border : 1px solid;  
}
#items td{
    border : 1px solid;
}
#items tbody{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
#items thead,.tbody{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">    
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 300px; "  id="items">
 <thead>
            <tr>
         <th style="width:100px;">Fee Type</th>
  <th style="width:100px;">Charges per Qty</th>
  <th style="width:100px;">Qty</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="tbody">
 <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">a</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">b</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;">d</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">e</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">f</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your logic is that `this` refers to the `td` already, so `closest('td')` isn't going to get the element you need. It's also not the parent of the `td` you want to target either, so `find()` won't work. You need to use `closest('tr')` instead:

```
var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text()
```

*However*, the simplest method to achieve this would be to just use `next()` as the `td` elements are siblings:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tbody').on('click', 'tr td:nth-child(1)', function() {
    var id = $(this).next().text();
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```css
#items {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#items th {
  background-color: #009999;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#items td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#items tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#items thead,
.tbody {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 300px; " id="items">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:100px;">Fee Type</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Charges per Qty</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Qty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;">a</td>
        <td style="width:100px;">b</td>
        <td style="width:100px;">c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;">d</td>
        <td style="width:100px;">e</td>
        <td style="width:100px;">f</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the closest element (td to tr) and you will get the expected result

```
var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
```